# DataTables sort by date function not working as desired

Tags: php, datatables

I have a table that has a column in unixtime.  I have a seconds->hours function i run to convert 125193852379857 to 1 day, 59 hours, 9 minutes and 26 seconds.

The problem is the Datatable's sort function.  if i have 3 values it would sort them as follows:

```
 1 day 2 hours 58 minutes and 26 seconds
 1 day 2 hours 59 minutes and 29 seconds
 1 day 2 hours 9 minutes and 42 seconds
```

I see why because it treats it as a "5" and not "58,59".

the conversion function:

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
 $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
 $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
 return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
 }
```

the table:

```
<tr><th>Total Time</th><td>secondsToTime(1209571298712)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Total Time</th><td>secondsToTime(1598173598862)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Total Time</th><td>secondsToTime(5283749872348)</td></tr>
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: One way is to print minutes with leading zeros (09 instead of 9). But as I read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), the parameter %i shlould already use leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `data-order` or `data-sort` attributes

**For example :**

```
    <td data-order="1303686000">Mon 25th Apr 11</td>
```

Read more from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Sort is working correctly, because by default it uses regular sort and sorts your values as string
(see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)).
You can try to use sort with SORT_NATURAL or [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: The question is more about problem with sorting on the client-side with [DataTables library](https://datatables.net/) and JavaScript rather than on server-side with PHP.